# Recuperar valor de variáveis dentro de um Classe em uma função Python (partial_fit)

Tags: python, classes, machine-learning

Estou criando um novo algoritmo para ser executado juntamente com os algoritmos disponibilizados pelo pacote *sklearn* em python, no entanto o *dataset* usado é extremamente grande e estou utilizando o função **partial_fit** (Exemplo: Naive Bayes [link](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/naive_bayes.py#L262)) para que consiga pegar blocos do *dataset* e executar o treinamento/teste. Porém essa função é recuperada várias vezes e algumas variáveis não podem perder o valor depois de retornadas a *Main*, para que seja possível atualizar os valores a cada incremento de bloco.

E estou na dúvida em como guardar esse valor dentro da função sem que ela seja reiniciada a cada nova chamada??? Observe que não quero o retorno delas a *Main* e sim que eles sejam armazenadas dentro da função de forma que consiga recupera-las posteriormente. E sem uso de variável GLOBAL.

Ex: [Code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/applications/plot_out_of_core_classification.html#main)

Trecho do Código:

```
for i, (X_train_text, y_train) in enumerate(minibatch_iterators):
    tick = time.time()
    X_train = vectorizer.transform(X_train_text)
    total_vect_time += time.time() - tick

    for cls_name, cls in partial_fit_classifiers.items():
        tick = time.time()
        # update estimator with examples in the current mini-batch
        
        # função é chamada várias vezes
        cls.partial_fit(X_train, y_train, classes=all_classes)

        # accumulate test accuracy stats
        cls_stats[cls_name]['total_fit_time'] += time.time() - tick
        cls_stats[cls_name]['n_train'] += X_train.shape[0]
        cls_stats[cls_name]['n_train_pos'] += sum(y_train)
        tick = time.time()
        cls_stats[cls_name]['accuracy'] = cls.score(X_test, y_test)
        cls_stats[cls_name]['prediction_time'] = time.time() - tick
        acc_history = (cls_stats[cls_name]['accuracy'],
                       cls_stats[cls_name]['n_train'])
        cls_stats[cls_name]['accuracy_history'].append(acc_history)
        run_history = (cls_stats[cls_name]['accuracy'],
                       total_vect_time + cls_stats[cls_name]['total_fit_time'])
        cls_stats[cls_name]['runtime_history'].append(run_history)
```

OBS: Veja que `cls.partial_fit` é chamado várias vezes por mais de um Classificador e ao final é incrementado um novo bloco do *dataset* e novamente os classificadores são chamados, porém mesmo assim as variáveis não perdem valores alocados dentro de suas funções. No caso do Naive Bayes ele ainda continua com os valores da última chamada para atualização. (Ex de variáveis atualizadas online Naive Bayes: média e desvio padrão)

Segue Vídeo para ajudar na explicação: [Link](https://youtu.be/J9UszAIIco4)

Comment: Quais variáveis você deseja manter os valores? Essa `partial_fit` é de sua implementação ou da biblioteca?

Comment: Olá esse `partial_fit` é um modelo padrão do esquema de implementação no Sklearn. No meu caso eu preciso manter uma matriz numpy ativa para a próxima iteração.

Comment: Segue vídeo para ajudar na Explicação: https://youtu.be/J9UszAIIco4